# while creating cordova project: incorrect header check at Zlib._binding.onerror (zlib.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, cordova-plugins

while i am creating a cordova project through the cmd on windows 7 i am getting the following error.

Error: incorrect header check
    at Zlib._binding.onerror (zlib.js:295:17)

we are using the cordova version of 3.6.3-0.2.13

Comment: I solved it for myself somehow but I don't remember how, there was some minor stupid mistake. Thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: could you recollect it..if you can ??

Comment: First of all, I was using linux. Secondly, if it was a fresh install and perhaps I didn't install it correctly or something like that. That's all I can remember, sorry